# Android: How can I use the Google maps

Tags: android, google-maps

Can someone explain how I can use the Google maps API in my project?
Cause I want to draw a marker on the map while moving the map with my finger.
But I don't know how to achieve this.

I am using the following code:

```
camCenter = mMap.getCameraPosition().target;

if (camCenter != null && camCenter != camCenterFirst) {
    CameraUpdate center =
    CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(camCenter.latitude,camCenter.longitude));
    CameraUpdate zoom = CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(16);

    mMap.moveCamera(center);
    mMap.animateCamera(zoom);
    camCenterFirst = camCenter;
}
```

Comment: Give us more info, code, what have u tried so far. And for the google-maps part look at [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start)

Comment: Don't place your code as answer, but edit your question please

Answer (score 0):

First you have to add a marker to your Map like this:

```
LatLng pos = new LatLng(53.557115, 10.023159);
Marker m = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(pos).title(""));
```

The example above, gives you a default position of the marker.
Then you can change the position of the marker with following command:

```
m.setPosition(new LatLng(latitude,longitude));
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
public void showOnMap(Double lat,Double lng,String place)

  MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(lat,
     lng)).title(""+place);

    mMap.addMarker(marker);

    CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(
            new LatLng(lat, lng)).zoom(12).build();
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

    double radiusInMeters = 5000.0;
    int strokeColor = 0xffff0000; //red outline
    int shadeColor = 0x44ff0000; //opaque red fill

    CircleOptions circleOptions = new CircleOptions().center(new LatLng(lat,lng)).radius(radiusInMeters).fillColor(shadeColor).strokeColor(strokeColor).strokeWidth(8);
    mMap.addCircle(circleOptions);

}
```

I have done a complete demo of what you are looking for,
Check this Github code

> https://github.com/cseshaiban/GeoApp